# Remount file system with 'nodev' option

Tags: centos, mount

I have this entry in file system:

```
/dev/sdb1        10G  1.5G   8.5G  15% /mnt/resource
```

I want to remount it with 'nodev' option. The biggest concern is losing the drive drive since it is on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass options to mount command with -o  I think it is similar on azure

```
mount -o nodev,remount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/resource
```